# JFET Hartley Oscillator's Transformer

Tags: rf, transformer, oscillator, high-frequency

I have designed a JFET hartley oscillator but I couldnt order the transformer in our circuit. Can anyone help me on this subject. The transformer's operating frequency is 1Mhz to 3.5 MHz and I could not find any company or person that can provide winding for this special transformer. If anyone has suggestion please let me know. Some engineers said if we use lower frequency transformer, the circuit will not work. On the other hand, we couldnt find any company that will provide us this transformer in our country. Please help me on this subject.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that I was answering your original question when you deleted it earlier today. This question also appears to be extremely similar to your first question and so why have you done this? I don't want to waste my time answering your original question only to find that you delete it at some point. I see nothing in this question that isn't a duplicate of your original question and, I will mark it as a duplicate but, I want your assurance that you won't delete your earlier question.

Comment: Anyway I have answered your [earlier original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660370/how-can-i-create-my-jfet-hartley-oscillators-transformer-in-real-life) (now that a moderator has undeleted it).

Comment: I apologise, I could see that you have answered the question. I appreciate that.